# Raspberry Pi: How to check I2C Bus Busy Status in Multi-Master mode

Tags: i2c, pigpio, wiringpi, raspberry-pi-os

I am working on the Wiring Pi I2C Example codes.
In my case, I am using the 2 masters over the same I2C Bus.
I am getting some errors like
0x00 + Missing ACK/NAK
Even the Clock pulse is not in 50% duty cycle.

Will you please help me to know...

1. How to solve this error?
2. How do I check the bus busy status over raspberry pi?

Regards,
Shiv Patil.

Comment: The Pi does not support multi-master mode.  There is no requirement for the I2C clock to be a square wave.

Answer (score 1):

1. The Pi does not support multi-master mode.
2. There is no requirement for the I2C clock to be a square wave.